# How to read date from an excel file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel-dates

How to read date from an excel file in JavaScript ?

When I fetched a date field from excel file, it comes like some integer/floating point number, how to display the original date present in the excel file.

Comment: How are you running this JavaScript? Are you writing an Excel plugin using JS? Are you reading the file from a JS program external to Excel (e.g. a Node.js program)? What code are you using to fetch the date field? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Fetched external excel file using ReactJs with the help of a get api (NodeJs)

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, when we fetch a date field from an excel file, it shows some integer/floating point number.
To convert the number back to date, we can use the following:

1. install **excel-date-to-js** package (npm i excel-date-to-js)
2. Run this snippet:

```
   const { getJsDateFromExcel } = require("excel-date-to-js") 
   getJsDateFromExcel(dateFieldFromExcelFile)   e.g. getJsDateFromExcel(data[1][0])
```

Comment: That module converts the date format from Excels internal format into a JS date object. It won't preserve the original date format in the spreadsheet.

Comment: We'll have to convert it to the format we want, it returns in the timestamp format.